# Error 105 when creating and writing to text file

Tags: delphi

I am testing a login and account creation program. When the user presses the Create New Account button it prompts them to enter a Username (which saves to a variable-sNewUsername) and a Password (which saves to a variable-sNewPassword). 
The password is saved to a text file.
For some reason, it gives me the 'I/O Error 105' when trying to save the password to the text file.

I have run the debug tool and it saves to the variable fine but does not Write to the text file.
I have double checked if I have used Rewrite instead of Reset and all looks fine.

```
AssignFile(tf,sNewUsername + '.txt');
Rewrite(tf);

  writeln(sNewPassword);

closefile(tf);
```

I expected the file to save the Password from the variable to the text file but it does not write the password to the text file and give an error i do not understand ('I/O error 105').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to `writeln` is not providing a file object, and so attempts to write to the standard output, which presumably does not exist in your process.

Change it to

```
writeln(tf, sNewPassword);
```

However, you should probably use a more modern mechanism to write a file. Further, you are running a serious risk that you won't write the file to the desired directory because you only specify a relative path.

Comment: I see, thanks for the advice. I will look into better methods.